# Warning: session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy intentando hacer un login utilizando la estructura MVC y me toma perfectamente los datos de la Base de Datos, sin embargo tengo el error ***Warning: session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent*** a la hora de iniciar sesión. Ya he intentado mover session_start()  hacia las primeras lineas del código pero sigo teniendo el mismo error. He podido comprobar que me toma los valores correctos de la BD ya que si pongo un usuario o contraseña que no esta en la BD me salta el error correspondiente, en cambio si pongo credenciales correctas sale este error en lugar de iniciar sesion

Aquí les comparto el código fuente de mi clase controladora. Si me pudiesen ayudarse lo agradecería.

```
    <?php
if ($peticionAjax) {
    require_once "../modelos/loginModelo.php";
} else {
    require_once "./modelos/loginModelo.php";
}

class loginControlador extends loginModelo {
    /* ---------- Controlador Iniciar Sesión ---------- */

    public function iniciar_sesion_controlador() {
        $email = mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['correo_log']);
        $clave = mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['pass_log']);

        /* ---------- Comprobar campos vacios ---------- */
        if (empty($email) || empty($clave)) {
            $this->mostrarMensajeError("No se han llenado todos los campos obligatorios");
            return;
        }

        /* ---------- Verificar correo electrónico ---------- */
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $this->mostrarMensajeError("El correo electrónico no tiene un formato válido");
            return;
        }

        /* ---------- Verificando integridad de los datos ---------- */
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9$@-]{1,100}$/", $clave)) {
            $this->mostrarMensajeError("La clave no coincide con el formato solicitado");
            return;
        }

        $clave = mainModel::encryption($clave);

        $datos_login = [
            "EMAIL" => $email,
            "CLAVE" => $clave
        ];

        $datos_cuenta = loginModelo::iniciar_sesion_modelo($datos_login);

        if ($datos_cuenta->rowCount() == 1) {
            $row = $datos_cuenta->fetch();

            session_start(['name' => 'STC']);

            $_SESSION['id_stc'] = $row['id_usuarios'];
            $_SESSION['email_stc'] = $row['usuario_email'];
            $_SESSION['nombre_stc'] = $row['usuario_nombre'];
            $_SESSION['rol_stc'] = $row['usuario_rol'];
            $_SESSION['token_stc'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

            header("Location: ".BASE_URL."estadisticas/");
        } else {
            $this->mostrarMensajeError("El correo electrónico o la contraseña son incorrectos");
            return;
        }
    }

    private function mostrarMensajeError($mensaje) {
        echo '
            <script>
                Swal.fire({
                title: "Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                text: "' . $mensaje . '",
                type: "error",
                confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
                confirmButtonText: "Aceptar"
            });
                
            </script>
        ';
    }

}
```

Comment: algo está saliendo antes del start ( session_start modifica/crea headers/cookies ), si se complica encontrar que cosa sale antes ponele un `die('--fin--');` antes del `session_start` y te fijas el response ( para ver el raw response por consola podes usar curl y less x ej `curl -ivs --raw https://www.google.com/ | less -X` )

Comment: Lo hice y no me sale nada en la consola, sigue sin funcionar

Comment: La instrucción `session_start` debe ser invocada al inicio del script; (por así decirlo) no después.

Comment: Intente poniéndolo en el inicio del archivo pero en vano igual